# Problema con campo varchar que contiene datos numericos y caracteres

Tags: java, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un programita que es una consulta de precios en `java` consultando una base de datos `SQL server`.

El usuario ingresa el código del producto  y le devuelve el precio y demás datos.

El problema es con en el campo `ProductoID (varchar)`, que tiene datos numéricos y alfanuméricos. Por ejemplo el código que la gente ingresa es **1356** y en la base el código es **001356**, por otro lado también existe el código **013561** y el SUPRABOND.110 , entonces no puedo encontrarle solución.

Probé con like pero no hubo éxito.

Codigo:

```
PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("select * from dbo.Productos where ProductoID LIKE ?");
            PreparedStatement pst2 = cn.prepareStatement("select * from dbo.Precios where ProductoID LIKE ? and CanalDeVentaID = 2");
            PreparedStatement pst3 = cn.prepareStatement("select * from dbo.CotizacionesDivisa where DivisaID = 2");
            PreparedStatement pst5 = cn.prepareStatement("select * from dbo.FormasDePago where FormaDePagoID = ?");
            PreparedStatement pst10 = cn.prepareStatement("select * from dbo.ExistenciasTemporarias where ProductoID LIKE ?");

    pst.setString(1, Codigo);
    pst2.setString(1, Codigo);
    pst10.setString(1, Codigo);

    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs2 = pst2.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs3 = pst3.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs10 = pst10.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Ponlo así: `like %?%`. Con el `%` le dices cualquier cosa antes y después de lo que contenga `?`

Comment: Si hago eso me tira el error: sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@p0'. Muchisimas gracias desde ya!

Comment: NO es evidente que la sugerencia de Lobos cause ese error. Podríás [edit] y AÑADIR el código de cómo probaste esa sugerencia, por favor?

Comment: Soy principiante, en el foro y en java. Modifique tantas veces que ahora no puedo mostrarte lo que había hecho, la próxima vez cuando responda a una ayuda copio el código que escribí según la sugerencia así pueden ver que estoy haciendo mal. Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un "cast" del campo que quieres que sea un entero (esto eliminaría los 00.. de adelante.

```
SELECT ... CAST(ProductID AS int) ...;
```

Comment: Hola, esto me re sirvió muchas gracias! Ahora me queda resolver cuando el usuario pone un código con texto como por ejemplo suprabond.110 y También cuando ponen un código de barras. Aclaro que el código de barras esta en otra tabla. No se si hacerlo con un if o con un case.